# Is a shoteh considered a gadol?

Tags: halacha, shoteh-mental-incompetent

If a katan (minor) is also a shoteh (insane) and then turns thirteen (and is physically mature), does he attain the status of a gadol, and if yes, are there any halachic ramifications?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50422/mental-disability-and-exemption-from-mitzvot

Comment: Perhaps a non Jew could no longer cut off his peyos once he ages into majority.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do Orthodox communities do for profoundly-disabled 13-year-olds (bar mitzvah or similar)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87750/what-do-orthodox-communities-do-for-profoundly-disabled-13-year-olds-bar-mitzva)

Comment: My question is not about bar mitzvah but about his status. Is he considered a gadol?  And if yes, are there any real practical ramifications.

Comment: One nafka mina is now the gadol can do yibbum. I'm sure there are more.

Comment: AFAIK shotah is its own category, so katan vs. gadol does not really apply. He can never be a "bar mitzvah" in the literal sense until he is cured.